# ReactJS localstorage.getItem is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

i have a problem with the localstorage.getItem, the setItem function is working fine and the data is stored correctly but when i refresh the page the data is gone.
Here is my codes

```
  useEffect(()=>{
localStorage.setItem(local_Storage_key, JSON.stringify(contacts));
}, [contacts]);

 useEffect(()=>{
    const storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(local_Storage_key));
    if (storage) {setContacts(storage);}
    }, []);
```

[picture of the localstorage before i refresh the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRxkl.png)

Comment: Are you in incognito mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's because your below code is executing after component has been mounted.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem(local_Storage_key, JSON.stringify(contacts));
}, [contacts]);
```

And because of this it is setting the initial value of contacts into the localStorage again.
To avoid this you can set the initial value of contacts to the value you get from the localStorage

```
const [contacts,setContacts] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(local_Storage_key)));

useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem(local_Storage_key, JSON.stringify(contacts));
}, [contacts]);

// remove another useEffect
```

Comment: Thanks brother, your answer gives me error but it lead me to solve the problem by checking if the contacts state is empty or not before set the local storage.
    if (contacts.length !== 0) localStorage.setItem(local_Storage_key,

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [useLocalStorage](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLocalStorage.md)

```js
import { useLocalStorage } from 'react-use';

const Demo = () => {
  const [value, setValue, remove] = useLocalStorage('my-key', 'foo');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Value: {value}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setValue('bar')}>bar</button>
      <button onClick={() => setValue('baz')}>baz</button>
      <button onClick={() => remove()}>Remove</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering about the same problem for several days. Finally I found a solution to the problem:

If you remove the `StrictMode` element from `index.js` file, the problem will be solved, and the `localStorage` data will persist when refreshing the page.
Best